# Babel 6: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (ref is a React component)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My react project cannot be built with current webpack settings.
My webpack version is 3.12.0

I am using old version of reactboilerplate and it's successful with webpack.dev.js however it does not work with webpack.prod.js. Here's my webpack setting:

```
// Important modules this config uses
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  entry: [
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js')
  ],

  // Utilize long-term caching by adding content hashes (not compilation hashes) to compiled assets
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 2,
      async: true
    }),

    // Minify and optimize the index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true
      },
      inject: true
    })
  ],

  performance: {
    assetFilter: (assetFilename) => !(/(\.map$)|(^(main\.|favicon\.))/.test(assetFilename))
  }
});
```

Here's what I got when "yarn build" is finished.

```
ERROR in ./app/components/Modal/FtpCredential/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:43)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
| var FtpCredential = function FtpCredential((_temp = _ref, _ref2 = <Button type="primary" ghost onClick={onCancel}>
|                   Cancel
|                 </Button>, _temp)) {
 @ ./app/containers/BaseModal/modalFactory.js 24:0-65
 @ ./app/components/Modal/index.js
 @ ./app/components/Modal/Modal.js
 @ ./app/containers/BaseModal/index.js
 @ ./app/containers/BaseModal/Loadable.js
 @ ./app/containers/App/index.js
 @ ./app/app.js
 @ multi ./app/app.js
```

Could you please help me to check?

Update 2: Here's my code before minifying with babel & webpack

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {compose} from "recompose";
import {Formik} from "formik";
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import {createStructuredSelector} from "reselect";
import Input from 'antd/lib/input';
import Form from 'antd/lib/form';
import Radio from 'antd/lib/radio';
import Checkbox from 'antd/lib/checkbox';

import Button from '../../Button';
import withFormHandlers from "./withFormHandlers";
import {clearPublishedResult} from "../../../containers/Editor/actions";
import {makeSelectPublishedResult} from "../../../containers/Editor/selectors";
import {openModal} from "../../../containers/BaseModal/actions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {makeSelectResponse} from "../../../containers/App/selectors";
import {API_SETTING} from "../../../utils/setting";
import {PUBLISH_METHOD} from "../../../utils/constants";

const { Item } = Form;
const { Group } = Radio;

const FtpCredential = ({
  item,
  validationSchema,
  onSubmit,
  onCancel,
  onClose,
  publishResult,
  publishFunnelResult,
  dispatch
}) => {
  const [slectedHostingType, setSelectedHostingType] = useState(item.data.defaultDeploymentLocation || PUBLISH_METHOD.DEFAULT);
  const ftpCredential = item.data.ftpCredential || {
    host: '',
    directory: '',
    port: 21,
    user: '',
    password: '',
    rememberDeploymentInfo: false
  };

  const awsS3Credential = item.data.awsS3Credential || {
    accessKeyId: '',
    bucketName: '',
    folder: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(publishResult)) {
      item.data.ftpCredential = {
        ...item.data.ftpCredential
      };
      onClose(item);
      let publishedResult = publishResult;
      let publishResultUrl = '';
      if (publishedResult.useDefaultDeploymentSetting) {
        publishResultUrl = publishedResult.siteDefaultHostingUrl;
      } else {
        publishResultUrl = item.data.domain;
      }
      const { trafficSources } = item.data;
      dispatch(openModal({
        type: "PublishResult",
        data: {
          publishResultUrl,
          trafficSources
        },
        onClose: () => dispatch(clearPublishedResult())
      }));
    }
  }, [publishResult]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(publishFunnelResult)) {
      onClose(item);
      let publishResultUrl = publishFunnelResult.publishedFunnelUrl;
      if (slectedHostingType === PUBLISH_METHOD.DEFAULT) {
        publishResultUrl = publishFunnelResult.siteDefaultHostingUrl;
      }

      dispatch(openModal({
        type: "PublishResult",
        data: {
          publishResultUrl
        },
        onClose: () => dispatch(clearPublishedResult())
      }));
    }
  }, [publishFunnelResult]);
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        id: item.data.id || "",
        host: ftpCredential.host || "",
        directory: ftpCredential.directory || "",
        port: ftpCredential.port || 21,
        user: ftpCredential.user || "",
        password: ftpCredential ? ftpCredential.password : '',
        defaultDeploymentLocation: item.data.defaultDeploymentLocation || PUBLISH_METHOD.DEFAULT,
        type: item.data.type || "",
        domain: item.data.domain || "",
        rememberDeploymentInfo: false,
        hostingDirectory: item.data.hostingDirectory || "",
        accessKeyId: awsS3Credential.accessKeyId,
        bucketName: awsS3Credential.bucketName,
        secretAccessKey: awsS3Credential.secretAccessKey || '',
        aws3Directory: awsS3Credential.folder
      }}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      validateOnChange={false}
      validateOnBlur={false}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          errors,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          setFieldValue
        } = props;
        return (
          <Form layout="horizontal">
            <Item>
              <Group
                value={values.defaultDeploymentLocation}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setFieldValue('defaultDeploymentLocation', e.target.value);
                  setSelectedHostingType(e.target.value);
                }}
              >
                <Radio value={PUBLISH_METHOD.DEFAULT}>Default CTRwow hosting</Radio>
                <Radio value={PUBLISH_METHOD.CUSTOM_FTP}>Custom FTP Hosting</Radio>
                <Radio value={PUBLISH_METHOD.AWS3}>AWS S3</Radio>
              </Group>
            </Item>
            { values.defaultDeploymentLocation === PUBLISH_METHOD.CUSTOM_FTP && (
              <Fragment>
                <Item
                  label="Host"
                  colon={false}
                  validateStatus={errors.host ? "error" : ''}
                  help={errors.host}
                >
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="host"
                    id="host"
                    placeholder="127.0.0.1"
                    value={values.host}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    size="large"
                  />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                  <Item
                    label="Directory"
                    colon={false}
                    validateStatus={errors.directory ? "error" : ''}
                    help={errors.directory}
                    hasFeedback
                    style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(50% - 12px)' }}
                  >
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      name="directory"
                      id="directory"
                      placeholder="/folder"
                      value={values.directory}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      size="large"
                    />
                  </Item>
                  <span style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}></span>
                  <Item
                    label="Port"
                    colon={false}
                    validateStatus={errors.port ? "error" : ''}
                    help={errors.port}
                    hasFeedback
                    style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(50% - 12px)' }}
                  >
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      name="port"
                      id="port"
                      value={values.port}
                      placeholder="Port"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      size="large"
                    />
                  </Item>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                  <Item
                    label="User"
                    colon={false}
                    validateStatus={errors.user ? "error" : ''}
                    help={errors.user}
                    hasFeedback
                    style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(50% - 12px)' }}
                  >
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      name="user"
                      id="user"
                      placeholder="Username"
                      value={values.user}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      size="large"
                    />
                  </Item>
                  <span style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}></span>
                  <Item
                    label="Password"
                    colon={false}
                    validateStatus={errors.password ? "error" : ''}
                    help={errors.password}
                    hasFeedback
                    style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(50% - 12px)' }}
                  >
                    <Input
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      id="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      value={values.password}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      size="large"
                    />
                  </Item>
                </Item>
              </Fragment>
            ) }
            {
              values.defaultDeploymentLocation === PUBLISH_METHOD.AWS3 && (
                <Fragment>
                  <Item>
                    <Item
                      label="Access Key ID"
                      colon={false}
                      validateStatus={errors.accessKeyId ? "error" : ''}
                      help={errors.accessKeyId}
                      hasFeedback
                      style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(50% - 12px)' }}
                    >
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="accessKeyId"
                        id="accessKeyId"
                        placeholder="Access Key ID"
                        value={values.accessKeyId}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        size="large"
                      />
                    </Item>
                    <span style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}></span>
                    <Item
                      label="API Key"
                      colon={false}
                      validateStatus={errors.secretAccessKey ? "error" : ''}
                      help={errors.secretAccessKey}
                      hasFeedback
                      style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: 'calc(50% - 12px)' }}>
                      <Input
                        name="secretAccessKey"
                        id="secretAccessKey"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Secret Access Key"
                        value={values.secretAccessKey}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        size="large"
                      />
                    </Item>
                  </Item>
                  <Item>
                    <Item
                      label="Bucket Name"
                      colon={false}
                      validateStatus={errors.bucketName ? "error" : ''}
                      help={errors.bucketName}
                      hasFeedback
                    >
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="bucketName"
                        id="bucketName"
                        placeholder="Bucket Name"
                        value={values.bucketName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        size="large"
                      />
                    </Item>
                    <Item
                      label="Directory"
                      colon={false}
                      validateStatus={errors.aws3Directory ? "error" : ''}
                      help={errors.aws3Directory}
                      hasFeedback
                    >
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="aws3Directory"
                        id="aws3Directory"
                        placeholder="/folder"
                        value={values.aws3Directory}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        size="large"
                      />
                    </Item>
                  </Item>
                </Fragment>
              )
            }
            {
              values.defaultDeploymentLocation !== PUBLISH_METHOD.DEFAULT && (
                <Item>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={e => {
                      setFieldValue('rememberDeploymentInfo', e.target.checked);
                    }}
                  >
                    Save this for next deployment
                  </Checkbox>
                </Item>
              )
            }
            <Item>
              <Item
                validateStatus={errors.domain ? "error" : ''}
                help={errors.domain}
                hasFeedback
              >
                <Input
                  type="hidden"
                  name="domain"
                  id="domain"
                  value={values.domain}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
              </Item>
              <Item
                style={{
                  textAlign: 'right',
                  paddingTop: '0.5rem'
                }}
              >
                <Button id={'btnCancelFtpCredential'} type={'primary'} ghost onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</Button>
                <Button
                  type={'primary'}
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >Publish</Button>
              </Item>
            </Item>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

FtpCredential.propTypes = {
  values: PropTypes.object,
  errors: PropTypes.object,
  isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func,
  handleBlur: PropTypes.func,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  item: PropTypes.object,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  onCancel: PropTypes.func,
  onClose: PropTypes.func,
  setFieldValue: PropTypes.func,
  validationSchema: PropTypes.any,
  publishResult: PropTypes.object,
  publishFunnelResult: PropTypes.object,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  publishResult: makeSelectPublishedResult(),
  publishFunnelResult: makeSelectResponse(API_SETTING.PUBLISH_FUNNEL.TAG)
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default compose(
  withConnect,
  withFormHandlers
)(FtpCredential);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to webpack.
You simply need to remove one parenthesis ( from the function definition.
Also, you have 2 parameters with the same name _temp, which will cause another error.

```
var FtpCredential = function FtpCredential(_temp = _ref, _ref2 = <Button type="primary" ghost onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</Button>, _temp2) {
```

Webpack production probably does some extra transpilations which detects the error.
Your ide probably alerts about it as well.

Comment: That code is output of UglifyJs so that I cannot moodify actually.
```javascript
"./app/components/Modal/FtpCredential/index.js": function(e, t) {
        throw new Error("Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:43)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.\n| \n| \n|
```

Comment: It is unlikely. Try search your client code (react) for this function.

Comment: It's our code too actually, I have just updated question with base code (before minifying)

Comment: Try removing the ghost parameter.

Comment: It does not work, I think the way babel creates _ref2 = (react component), it does not look like a valid syntax?

Comment: Try to remove this button component completely. I'm sure it is something in your code and not babel.

Comment: Sorry for replying lately, we found out that we are using old version of boilerplate (which contains old version webpack, babel and its relative babel-plugin-react-transform --> currently deprecated and it does not support transform hook pretty well so minified bundle may be crashed)
SOLUTION: 
- Upgrade our react-boilerplate version (using better babel hook transpile)